# DownloadStringTaskAsync Result DeadLock when using UI

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await, deadlock

This is my code:

```
Dim getUrlContentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() GetUrlContent(modifiedUrl))
getUrlContentTask.Wait()

'Check #6 - Check if the url has an expired text in it.
CheckIfExpired(getUrlContentTask)

Public Shared Function GetUrlContent(url As String) As task(of String)

    Try

        Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim webContent = Await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url)

        Return webContent
End Function

Public Shared Function CheckIfExpired(webContent As Task(Of String) As Boolean

    If util.ExpiredTexts.Any(Function(o) webContent.Result.Contains(o)) = False Then
        Throw New UriFormatException("Url leads to an expired page")
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

When this function runs without UI it runs fine, but when i try to run it via UI it stucks in 
**webContent.Result.contains(o)**

How can i a make it work using UI?

Comment: You are explicitly blocking by calling `Result` or `Wait()`. Don't do that. Use `await` to await asynchronously and receive the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deadlocking on the UI thread because `Task.Result` is blocking. You need to use async-await instead.

Change your function to return `Task(Of String)`, add the `Async` keyword and the Async suffix to the function name (which is the naming convention):

```
Public Shared Async Function GetUrlContentAsync(url As String) As Task(Of String)
    Try

        Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim webContent = Await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url)

        Return webContent
        End Function
```

Comment: When i tried that and it gets stuck it the next function where i use the webContent.result.

Comment: *Don't* call .Result. `await` returns the result of the asynchronous operation.

Comment: I need to check later if the result contain something , how do i call it then?

Comment: @OffirPe'er You should use `async-await` all the way up. At the very top it's probably an event handler which should by `async void`.